# Make DOM live update with SvelteKit and Supabase

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, supabase, supabase-database

I am using SvelteKit with Supabase. Whenever the form is submitted I would like to see the DOM live update. However, it takes a refresh to see the changes.
How would I live update the DOM whenever a new row is inserted into the table?

```js
<script>
    import { supabase } from '$lib/supabaseClient'

    const getData = async function() {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('scores')
        .select('*')

        return data
    }

    let newRowName = '';
    let newRowScore = 0;
    const postData = async function(nameVal, scoreVal) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('scores')
        .insert([{ name: nameVal, score: scoreVal }])
    }
</script>

{#await getData()}
    <p>Waiting...</p>
{:then data}
    {#each data as singleData}
        <p>{singleData.name}: {singleData.score}</p>
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p>Error occured</p>
{/await}

<form on:submit|preventDefault="{() => postData(newRowName, newRowScore)}">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id='name' bind:value='{newRowName}' required />
    <label for="score">Score:</label>
    <input type="number" id='score' bind:value='{newRowScore}' required />

    <button>Add row</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

hilo!

The only way to do something when the data is changed is by using [supabase realtime](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/subscribe) however i am not 100% how one would reload the DOM but i would try to use [goto(*current route*)](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto).
I do not have i computer accesible so i cannot confirm that that would reload the DOM although i believe it should.

This is 1 way it could be solved using what i just said:

```
(async () => {const mySubscription = supabase
  .from('scores')
  .on('insert', (payload) => {
    goto(current route)
  })
  .subscribe()})()
```

Tho that would mean that if anyone where to insert to the table it would reload which i would assume isn’t good but i guess you could just use goto() in the post function as such:

```
const postData = async function(nameVal, scoreVal) {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('scores')
    .insert([{ name: nameVal, score: scoreVal }])
 if (data) goto(route)
}
```

As long as goto() indeed does reload the DOM, it solves the problem that the user would have to reload the page manually but… the page is reloaded, not updated

Comment: I acctually think you can scrap the first idea completely. There are just so many bad things with that solution.

Comment: That’s a clever approach to solve the problem, even though a reload is required which isn’t optimal. However, not needing additional dependencies like supabase realtime is also a plus. I’ll give it a shot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about rows that you have inserted yourself via the current page, you can probably just update the local state.

Something along the lines of this:

```js
// Local state, so it can be updated
let rows = null;

const getData = async function() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('scores')
        .select('*');

    // Update local state only
    rows = data;
}

// ...

const postData = async function(nameVal, scoreVal) {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('scores')
        .insert([{ name: nameVal, score: scoreVal }])

    // Assuming that data will be the row
    rows = [...rows, data];
}
```

```html
{#await getData()}
    <p>Waiting...</p>
{:then _}
    {#each rows as row}
        <p>{row.name}: {row.score}</p>
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p>Error occured</p>
{/await}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use enhance as explained here:[Customising use:enhance](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance)

combined with a store in order to have reactive data.

```
<script>
   const dataStore = writable();
   const data = await getData();
   dataStore.set(data);
</script>


{#each $dataStore as row }
  ...
{/each}


<form
method="POST"
use:enhance={() => {
    return async ({ result }) => {
        
        // You would access the updated values here and update the DOM 
           by updating the store value.

        // Something along those lines... 
         dataStore.set(result.data);
    };
}}
>
```